# Laravel blade one-to-one relationship in @foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I have a problem with show one to one relationship in Laravel.

I have that tables in DB:
*manufacturers* with defaul Laravel id column and *cashregisters* with manufacturer_id column releated to id from *manufacturers* table.

In models I do that:

**Cashregister**

```
class Cashregister extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cashregisters";

    public function manufacturer(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Manufacturer','id');

    }
}
```

**Manufacturer**

```
class Manufacturer extends Model
{
    protected $table = "manufacturers";

    public function cashregisters(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cashregister');

    }
}
```

I think this is ok. Next I do in CashregisterController that in index():

```
$cashregisters = Cashregister::all();
return view('cashregisters.index')->withCashregisters($cashregisters);
```

In cashregisters index View i do that loop:

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($cashregisters as $cashregister)
    <tr>
    <th>{{ $cashregister->id }}</th>
    <td>{{ $cashregister->manufacturer_id }}</td>
                         ......
    <td>{{ $cashregister->DataNastPrzegUrzFisk }}</td>
    @endforeach
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And it works great. Show everything from *cashregisters* table.

I want to display Manufacturer name instead of manufacturer_id, so I try do this that:

```
 <td>{{ $cashregister->manufacturer->name }}</td>
```

Bu I got an error.

Next I searchover internet and try do that thing

```
@foreach ($cashregisters as $cashregister)
        <tr>
        <th>{{ $cashregister->id }}</th>
      @foreach ($cashregister->manufacturer() as $item)
        <td>{{ $item->name}}</td>
      @endforeach
                             ......
        <td>{{ $cashregister->DataNastPrzegUrzFisk }}</td>
        @endforeach
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

But this piece of code show nothing :( Can anyone help me to fix that. When I after all table do that code:

```
<td>{{ $cashregister->manufacturer->name}}</td>
```

it show some information, so I think relationship is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set local key for manufacturer, like this:

```
    class Cashregister extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cashregisters";

    public function manufacturer(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Manufacturer','id', 'manufacturer_id');

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved a problem :) I whitnk that it serahc for "manufacturer_id" manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load the relation:

```
$cashregisters = Cashregister::with('manufacturer')->all();
```

Then this will show the manufacturer:

```
$cashregister->manufacturer->name
```